# Unable to update package body in SQL developer

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL Developer 4.0.0.13 to connect to Oracle 11g DB. Now I have a package that I need to update its body, I open the package body in the editor, do my change then

1) right click compile

2) right click compile for debug

3) save (ctrl+s)

For all the above the new changes are not saved... When I close the package body editor and open it again I don't find my changes. I tried closing the app and opening it again but nothing helped... Any ideas??? It seems it caches or something like that.

***Update***

I tried updating it from a peer's machine, which worked fine... It seems the problem is in my version... By the way it was working well before.

***Update***

Same happens if try to edit any database entity (function/procedure/...).

Comment: Is there something specific in your preferences that is preventing the save process? Perhaps re-install SQLDeveloper?

Comment: I want to keep this the last option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the reason, I just needed to put the schema name as a prefix to the package body ....... but the weird thing is that the SQL developer didn't complain, It just printed a message 'compiled'